# Python Script using pandas to plot histograms between the features

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, kaggle, ipython

I am working around with data from Kaggle : Titanic Competition dataset.

**Script**

```py
#cols : List of all column header
cols = list(df.columns.values) 
#script to plot histograms of all columns with respect to column: "Survived"
for val in cols:
       df.groupby('Survived')[val].hist(alpha = 0.2)
```

**Code of importance (COI)**

```py
df.groupby('Survived')['Age'].hist(alpha = 0.3)
```

*Output*

[image: output]

The *COI* works but the *Script* is not working. The script will help to plot all the histograms in one go without manually inserting the column in the *COI*.

1. The script is running indefinetly.
2. The *COI* also runs indefinetly but once I execute the following code:

```py
df.groupby('Survived').Age.hist(alpha = 0.2) #This runs flawlessly
```

*COI* runs perfectly. (Not able to figure out why).

3. The scripts are written in Kaggel Kernel.

Given the above details, please help me figure out a way to achieve the above script either by making improvements to the *Script* or an alternate way of doing the same.

Comment: Add plt.show() after that line

Comment: I meant use seaborn or something like that for the plot and then add explicitly that

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = list(df.columns.values) 
for val in cols:
        df.groupby('Survived')[val].hist(alpha = 0.2)
        plt.show()
```

just add plt.show() in the end it would create histogram for all columns